# Building a multi lingual supported web application (with e.g. English, German etc.)

Tags: angular, web

I want to build a web application with Angular 2/ Angular 4 and I want to support various lingual languages like English, French and German... I do want to store them locally and not on a server or so. In Android there are e.g. *strings.xml* files for every language, which is supported by the application. Can I do here something similar, maybe with Angular services?
I would appreciate an elegant solution approach! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:
[INTERNATIONALIZATION (I18N)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html#!#angular-i18n)